# Can't add product to cart in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopping-cart

I'm building a shopping cart (Rails 4).

I can successfully add a product to the cart but the cart view displays the following error message  :

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (no method error)
```

Here is my `cart.rb` :

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :produits, through: :items

  attr_reader :items

    def self.build_from_hash(hash)
        items = if hash ["cart"] then
            hash["cart"] ["items"].map do |item_data|
        Item.new item_data["produit_id"], item_data["quantite"]
        end

    else
        []
    end

        new items
    end


   def initialize(items = [])
     @items = items
   end

   def add_item(produit_id)
     item = @items.find { |item| item.produit_id == produit_id }
     if item
       item.increment
     else
       @items << Item.new(produit_id)
     end
   end

   def serialize
    items = @items.map do |item|
        {
            "produit_id" => item.produit_id,
            "quantite" => item.quantite
        }
    end
    { "items" => items }


   end

   def total_price
     @items.inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + item.total_price }
   end


end
```

Here is `produit.rb`

```
class Produit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  validates :artisan, presence: true
  validates :categorie, presence: true
  validates :stock, presence: true
  validates :visible, presence: true
  validates :denomination, presence: true
  validates :titre, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :ref, presence: true
  validates :prix, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

Here is `item.rb` :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :produit

  attr_reader :produit_id, :quantite

  def initialize(produit_id, quantite = 1)
    @produit_id = produit_id
    @quantite = quantite
  end

  def increment
    @quantite = @quantite + 1
  end

  def produit
    Produit.find(produit_id)
  end

  def total_price
    produit.prix * quantite
  end

end
```

I can also give the controllers so you can see everything :

carts controller:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  def show
  end

  def add_to_cart
        @cart.add_item params[:id]
        session["cart"] = @cart.serialize
        produit = Produit.find(params[:produit_id])
        redirect_to :back, notice: "#{produit.titre} a bien été ajouté au panier."
    end

  def destroy
    cart = session['cart']
    item = cart['items'].find { |item| item['produit_id'] == params[:id] }

    produit = Produit.find(item['produit_id'])
    produit.update_columns(quantite: produit.quantite + 1)

    if item
      cart['items'].delete item
    end
    redirect_to cart_path
   end

end
```

Produits controller :

```
class ProduitsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_cart
  before_action :set_produit, only: [:show]

  def index
    @produits = Produit.all
  end

  def show
    @produit  = Produit.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def set_produit
    @produit = Produit.find(params[:id])
  end

  def produit_params
    params.require(:produit).permit(:denomination, :titre, :description, :artisan,
                                    :categorie, :stock,  :visible, :prix, :ref, :image)
  end

end
```

application controller :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def initialize_cart
    @cart = Cart.build_from_hash session
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :rememberme,
            :civilite, :prenom, :nom, :date_naissance, :majeur, :newsletter, :email_parrain])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:email, :password, :rememberme])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :rememberme,
            :civilite, :prenom, :nom, :date_naissance, :majeur, :newsletter, :email_parrain,
            :fixe, :mobile, :adresse, :cp, :ville, :pays, :current_password])
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
      root_path
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Finally, cart show view:

```
<%= content_for :title, "Mon Panier" %>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/navbar' %>

<%= render partial: 'carts/header' %>

<div id="retour-boutique">
  <%= link_to 'Retourner à la boutique', produits_path %>
</div>

<section id="panier-container">
  <div id="panier-left-container">
    <% if @cart.present? %>
      <div id="item-cart-description">
        <p>Article</p>
        <p>Description</p>
        <p>Quantité</p>
        <p>Prix unitaire</p>
        <p>Prix global</p>
      </div>
      <% @cart.produits.each do |produit| %>
        <div id="item-cart-container">
          <div class="produit-image">
            <%= image_tag produit.image %>
          </div>
          <div class="produit-description">
            <p><%= produit.titre %></p>
          </div>
          <div class="produit-quantite">
            <div class="quantite-increment-container">
              <!-- Increment/decrement method -->
              <div>—</div>
              <div>1</div>
              <div>+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="delete-item">
              <p><%= link_to 'Supprimer l\'article' %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="produit-prix">
            <p><%= number_to_currency(produit.prix, unit: '€', format: "%n%u") %></p>
          </div>
          <div class="produit-prix-quantite">
            <p><%= number_to_currency(produit.prix, unit: '€', format: "%n%u") %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="panier-right-container">
      <div id="code-total">
        <div class="code-promo">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Code promo"><!--
          --><input type="submit" value="OK">
          <div>
            <p>- 0,00€</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panier-total">
          <div>
            <p>Total (hors frais de port)</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price, unit: '€', format: '%n%u') %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="panier-etape-suivante">
        <%= link_to 'Commander', commandes_produits_breton_path %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div id="no-item-in-cart">
      <p>Votre panier est vide !</p>
    </div>

    <div id="aller-boutique">
      <%= link_to 'Aller à la boutique', produits_path %>
    </div>
  <% end %>


</section>
```

and the error message :

```
Started GET "/mon-panier" for ::1 at 2017-07-11 13:49:10 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (16.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
  User Load (6.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1999.7ms)
  Rendered carts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2013.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2076ms (ActiveRecord: 38.8ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    18:         <p>Prix unitaire</p>
    19:         <p>Prix global</p>
    20:       </div>
    21:       <% @cart.produits.each do |produit| %>
    22:         <div id="item-cart-container">
    23:           <div class="produit-image">
    24:             <%= image_tag produit.image %>
  app/views/carts/show.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb__2068073620096962008_70106924027180'


  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (73.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (84.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (152.6ms)
```

I couldn't find any answer in similar questions. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share complete error backtrace, and carts/show.html.erb

Comment: @NimishGupta i've edited the question

Comment: Seems like `session` is nil in `initialize_cart`. What do you have in `session`? Try inspecting it like `puts session.inspect` and paste the result here.

Comment: @Pavan the error message is very long:  `@serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>, @serializer=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer>>>, "action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie"=>{"session_id"=>"6d06e0b85f233393a7a50787789d0675",`

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (no method error)

The root cause of the error is `session` being `nil` in `initialize_cart` where you are sending `session` as an argument to `build_from_hash` method in `application_controller.rb`

```
def initialize_cart
  @cart = Cart.build_from_hash session
end
```

Make sure `session` is **not** `nil`

Comment: how to make sure session  is not nil?

Comment: @justinedps26 I will tell you. Can you tell me what are trying to do in `build_from_hash` method?

Comment: just trying to initialize the cart session but you can do it another way if you want

Answer (score 0):

As Pavan said session is nil.

Problem fixed by changing the `initialize_cart` method like so:

```
def initialize_cart
    @cart = Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart_id], user: session[:user_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    puts session.inspect
  end
```

more robust and secure